# how to customise the look of carousal slider in flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, slider, carousel

I'm using [flutter_carousel_widget](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_carousel_widget) package to make a carousel with this code:

```
 FlutterCarousel(
    options: CarouselOptions(
                physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                controller: _carouselController,
                onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                  currentView = index + 1;
           //setState is called to update the current page with respect to the current view
                  setState(() {});
                },
                height: 50.0,
                indicatorMargin: 10.0,
                showIndicator: true,
                slideIndicator: CircularWaveSlideIndicator(),
                viewportFraction: 0.9,
              ),
              items: swipeList.map((i) {
                return const Text('');
              }).toList(),
),
```

The above code outputs this kind of Carousel slider:

[image: Result]

But I would like to change the look of Corousel slider like below:

[image: Expected]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following code:

```
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_options.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
class Home extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          height: 200,
          color: Colors.black,
          child:
          CarouselSlider(
              options: CarouselOptions(
                //  height: 100,

                viewportFraction: .15,
                enlargeCenterPage: true,
                enableInfiniteScroll: false,
                aspectRatio: 16/5,
                disableCenter: true,
                enlargeFactor: 0.35,
                //autoPlay: true,

              ),
              items: List.generate(10, (index) => Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                ),
              ))
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

the result:

[image]

Hope it helps you.